# Що означає слово "пиндик"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

У пісні [Ой, служив я в пана...](http://www.pisni.org.ua/songs/442333.html) є невідоме слово "**пиндик**":

> Ой, служив я в пана, та й на третє літо,
>
> Заробив я в пана індика за літо.
>
> А той індик, пиндик-пиндик,
>
> А та кача дрібно скаче...

У [СУМі11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pyndyk) є така стаття:

> **ПИ́НДИК**, а, чол., рідко. Те саме, що **принда**.

Якщо пройти за вказаним у СУМі посиланням **[принда](http://sum.in.ua/s/prynda)**, вибиває, що слова «принда» не знайдено.

То що ж означає слово "**пиндик**" у пісні?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Цїкаво, натрапили на помилку, котрої має і паперова, сторінки: [приневолєвати](http://sum.in.ua/p/7/688/2), [пиндючливо](http://sum.in.ua/p/6/355/2). Причім на *принда* посилається також [*пинда*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pynda).

Звісно, [відповідь](/a/4649/585) є  правильною. Також наголошу, що значіння слів можна знаходити через похідні, наприклад з того ж СУМ:

> [**Приндитися**](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryndytysja), джуся, дишся, *недок.*, *фамільярне*.
>
> 1. Виявляти пиху, гордощі; бундючитися. *Він коли не з огидою, так з великою неохотою.. почав наймати оцю погану, рябу молодицю, а вона ще й приндиться!..* (Любов Яновська, I, 1959, 43); *— Це був маленький конторник, але носа задирав так високо, що робітники навіть не ображались на його зневагу, а тільки сміялись. Приндиться, як гиндик, так у гиндика хоч хвіст поцяцькований!* (Петро Панч, Синів.., 1959, 82).
> 2. Триматися по-молодецькому; бадьоритися, козиритися. *— Ти що ж оце? Мене як квочку курчатами обсадив, а сам тут півником приндишся біля молодесеньких!* (Вага, На.. дорозі, 1967, 195); *— Не хорохорся, Степане. Не та в тебе ситуація. Можна сказати, одною ногою в могилі стоїш, а приндишся* (Іван Цюпа, Краяни, 1971, 386).
> 3. Сердитися. *Уляна неприязно мовчала, приндилася* (Костянтин Гордієнко, I, 1959, 156); *— Ніяк не вговтаю татуся. Лементує, приндиться, а спитати б чого? Бач, спалила його старий костюм* (Віталій Логвиненко, Давні рани, 1961, 154).

Як бачно, слово може мати широко вжитку. Але, правда, воно переважно є сутямкою до щось *бундючого*:

> [**Пиндючитися**](http://sum.in.ua/s/pyndjuchytysja), чуся, чишся, *недок.*, *розмовне*
>
> Те саме, що [бундючитися](http://sum.in.ua/s/bundjuchytysja). *Фесенко ставав в мальовничій позі, переступав з ноги на ногу, пиндючивсь, силкувався бути граціозним в манерах* (Нечуй-Левицький, V, 1966, 155); *Згадуючи батьківські достатки, по-качиному пиндючилась [Олена] перед чоловіком і щодня точила його, мов шашіль деревину* (Михайло Стельмах, Хліб.., 1959, 234).
>
> ---
>
> [**Пиндючливий**](http://sum.in.ua/s/pyndjuchlyvyj), а, е, *розмовне*
>
> Те саме, що [бундючний](http://sum.in.ua/s/bundjuchnyj). *Вона втекла мерщій, лишивши пиндючливого пана Пампушку з Оврамом Роздобудьком на самоті* (Олександр Ільченко, Козацькому роду.., 1958, 264).
>
> ---
>
> [**Пиндючнай**](http://sum.in.ua/s/pyndjuchnyj), а, е, розм. Те саме, що [бундючний 1](http://sum.in.ua/s/bundjuchnyj). Пиндючна пиха.
>
> ---
>
> [**Пиндючити**](http://sum.in.ua/s/pyndjuchyty), чу, чиш, *недок.*, *перех.*, *розмовне*.
>
> Те саме, що [настовбурчувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/nastovburchuvaty). *— Хіба оцей біляк вас з глузду звів? — Один Гусак загомонів. — Чого ви, братця, так баньки, повитріщали? — Ми попелясті всі, а він один між нас Своє пиндючить пір'я біле!* (Євген Гребінка, I, 1957, 44).
>
> **Пиндючити ніс** (**морду** і т. ін.), *вульгарне*. — бундючитися. *Пиндючить ніс Остапова Горпина І, знай, все мацає на шиї свій дукач* (Гулак-Артемовський, Байки.., 1958, 127); *[Герасим:] Ах ти ж погань! Мужва репана! Давно лизала панам руки, за верству шапки скидала, а тепер розжилася, кумпанію з панами водить і зараз морду пиндючить перед своїм братом!* (Карпенко-Карий, I, 1960, 400).

Comment: `Цїкаво`, `значіння`, `Як бачно`, `помилку, котрого має` (помилка жіночого роду) , `сутямкою до щось бундючого` - шо тово за правопис такий? Збиваєте з пантелику люди, якї шукають вїдповїдї на питання про грамотнїсть.

Comment: @user2513149 [бачно](http://sum.in.ua/s/bachno), [значінньа](http://sum.in.ua/s/znachinnja), [тьамка](https://archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt) від [тьама](http://sum.in.ua/s/tjama). Ньічого складного. Про [**ї**](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Желехівка), вона переважно заміньује лиш **і** (і не всьуди, јак ви намагалисьа), яких пошук не розріжньаје — шчо тут, шчо Google. I це [можна](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/). Також зазначу, шчо то не кльучові слова. Про рід — дьакују, виправив. Шчось шче?

Answer (score 3):

У [Великому тлумачному словнику сучасної української мови. - "Перун". 2005.](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/120589/%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA) знаходимо:

> **пиндик**
>   -а, ч., рідко.
>   Те саме, що принда.

За відсиланням знаходимо:

> **принда**
>   -и.
>   1) ж. Пиха, бундючність.
>   2) ч. і ж., діал. Пихата, бундючна людина.